# How to render responsive and blurred images on load with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, blur, nextjs-image

I am trying to blur my images when they are loading, but I am unable to find a comprehensive and understandable solution. Currently, in Next.js, I am using the `<img/>` tag to define how my image looks. However, after looking into Next's built-in `<Image/>` tag, I think that it is more performant and feature rich than the simple `<img/>` tag.

In trying to convert my old code to the next Next tag, I have run into a few issues:

1. I loose control over the styling of the image
2. The blurring still does not appear

This is my original code:

```js
<img
  src={images[0].url}
  alt={images[0].altText}
  className="object-cover w-full h-64 rounded-md"
/>
```

And the Next Image tag code

```js
<Image
  src={images[0].url}
  alt={images[0].atlText}
  width={300} // I want a 100% width, not fixed
  height={200}
  placeholder="blur"
  blurDataURL="https://abstackwp.khingars.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-blur-placeholder.png"
/>
```

As you can tell, I am loading images from an external API.

In short, how can I both style my images to be responsive and blurred while loading?

Comment: The [`blurDataURL`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#blurdataurl) value has to be a base64-encoded image. You can use a library like [plaiceholder](https://plaiceholder.co/docs/usage) to encode it (note that plaiceholder is a Node.js library, and only works in a Node.js environment, not in the browser).

Comment: For the styling I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#styling.

Comment: Why did they decide such a stupid thing as using based64 images? How will we obtain such an image before fetching the intended one?